# Adding packages to an existing layer in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a layer in my work AWS account which contains many python libraries like pandas, numpy, sqlalchemy, etc.
It has a folder structure of

```
-> LayerName:
     ->  python
          ->  pandas
          ->  numpy
              ......
```

I want to add my custom package also to this layer. How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking for? You can't add files to existing layer. You have to recreate it and replace, or make it as a new version.

Comment: My question was intended to know whether I could add files to an existing layer. Got it from your answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add new packages to your Lambda layer, you would need to deploy a [new version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-manage) of the Layer containing the original packages as well as the new packages you wanted to add.

You can get the contents of a layer version by running [get-layer-version](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/get-layer-version.html) and copying the contents from the `Content.Location` value.

Alternatively you would create a new Lambda layer and package these other packages into that.

Comment: So, I will anyway have to manually add these packages into that folder structure and then zip it and reupload it into layers, right?

Comment: Exactly ;). Just ensure all other packages are there too :)